# Не могу записать значения из ресурса в TabControl->tabPage

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

```
 private:System::Void ChangeLanguage(String^ lang) {

     CultureInfo^ newCultureInfo = gcnew CultureInfo(lang);

     ComponentResourceManager^ resources = gcnew ComponentResourceManager(this->GetType());
     for each (Control^ c in this->Controls)
     {
         resources->ApplyResources(c,c->Name, newCultureInfo);
     }
}
```

В цикле присваиваются значения из файла ресурса с указаной культуры "lang" 
Проблема в том что на форме есть TabControl с двумя страницами и MenuStrip, все контролы которые находятся вне этих двух контролов присваиваются нормально а в этих двух элементах не хотят.
Подскажите в какую сторону смотреть ?

И да , если контролу находящемуся в TabControl попробовать пременить ресур то все получится успешно, а в цикле не хочет.

```
 resources->ApplyResources(TestPrintBT, "TestPrintBT", newCultureInfo);
```

Comment: Метод `ApplyResources` [нужно вызывать](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11738932/5045688) рекурсивно для всех потомков. В чём смысл задавать кучу одинаковых вопросов, ни в одном из них не приведя код этого метода?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov я не совсем понял как именно, можно кодом? извините я новичек